# No module named [filename] Python

Tags: python, module

I am trying to import **Navigator** class **in renameFrame.py** from **navigator.py** but, it's giving me an error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'navigator'** In the below image you can see the directory structure.

[image]

**Here is an image of the Navigator.py file**

[image]

Thank you so much for your help .

Comment: Please share your code in text format so others can replicate it. Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ashutosh Porwal Ok sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 dropped support for implicit relative imports. You need to make the import absolute or explicitly relative by adding a leading `.`:

```
from .navigator import Navigator
```

Since you're running `rename.py`, the `Bunch File Rename` directory will be in `sys.path`, but `Bunch File Rename/packages` is not. Due to this, `navigator.py` is not on any of the paths where python searches for packages.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
from packages.navigator import Navigator
```